# error in my code ?(sorting array using function and pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

There are two program both work correct , can you explain me why?

```
//sorting of array using pointers
#define n 5
void sort(int m,int *x);
main()
{
    int i,a[n];

    printf("enter the values");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    sort(n,a);//not sending the address but still my code works only when I define array but when i use int data type then I need to pass address , why is this so?
}
void sort(int m,int *x)
{
    int i,j,temp,k;
    for(i=1;i<=m-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=m-1;j++)//this lop is to sort array
        {
            if(*(x+j-1)>=*(x+j))
            {
                temp=*(x+j-1);
                *(x+j-1)=*(x+j);
                *(x+j)=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(k=0;k<m;k++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n",*(x));
        x++;//when i am not using *x++
    }
}
```

my progrm doest change or doesnt  give error when i use this program

```
//sorting of arrays sing pointers
    #define n 5
    void sort(int m,int *x);
    main()
    {
        int i,a[n];

        printf("enter the values");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        sort(n,&a);//and '&a' instead of 'a'
    }
    void sort(int m,int *x)
    {
        int i,j,temp,k;
        for(i=1;i<=m-1;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=m-1;j++)//this loop is to sort array
            {
                if(*(x+j-1)>=*(x+j))
                {
                    temp=*(x+j-1);
                    *(x+j-1)=*(x+j);
                    *(x+j)=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(k=0;k<m;k++)
        {
            printf("\n%d\n",*(x));
            *x++;//here i have used *x++ instead of x++
        }
    }
```

why is it necessary to pass adress in function call when we define  `int` data type and we do not need to pass address in array when calling a function , when we are woring in pointers?
kindl clear my doubt.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`, least. Where are the `include`s?

Answer (score 1):

Your compilation *results* should certainly have changed.

Passing `&a` to a function expecting `int *` should have at-least flagged a compiler warning, and with any reasonably current standard compliant compiler, an outright error. The types `int *` and `int(*)[5]` are not synonymous. I don't know what toolchain you're using, but anything current should puke. For example, using `std=c11` and clang 3.5 gives:

> Incompatible pointer types passing 'int (*)[5]' to parameter of type 'int *'

Regardless, an array used in an expression as yours undergoes conversion to a pointer-to-type (in your case the type is `int`) who's value is the address of the first element in the sequence. Passing it as a parameter to a function results in such an expression, and thus such a conversion to a temporary pointer to `int`.

Thus,

```
foo(int *x);

int main()
{
    int ar[5];
    foo(ar);
}
```

results in `x` holding the address of `ar`'s first element. The first element of an array also must reside at the address of the array itself, so strictly speaking the address expressed from `ar` and `&ar` are the *same address*. But the **types** of the pointer conversion results of those expressions are different. In the former case the pointer type is `int *`; a pointer to `int`. With the latter the type is `int (*)[5]`; a pointer to array-of-5-`int`. If you think it doesn't make a difference it certainly *can*, in particular with pointer arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define n 5

int main()
{
    int ar[n];

    printf("ar    = %p\n", ar);
    printf("ar+1  = %p\n", ar+1);
    printf("&ar   = %p\n", &ar);
    printf("&ar+1 = %p\n", &ar+1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (Yours will vary, but differences should be similar)

```
ar    = 0x7fff5fbffa20
ar+1  = 0x7fff5fbffa24
&ar   = 0x7fff5fbffa20
&ar+1 = 0x7fff5fbffa34
```

Note how both `ar` and `&ar` reflect the same address, but pointer arithmetic of adding `1` demonstrates a significant difference when applied. That difference is due to the different *type* of these pointers. In the first it bumps by the size of an `int`. In the second it bumps by the size of an `int[5]`

<sub>Apologies to the purists that want all those addresses cast to `void*`. Sorry, its late.</sub>

---

Regarding `x++` vs `*x++`, that is [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) at work. The postfix operator `++` has higher precedence than indirection `*`. As a result the solitary expression `*x++;` is effective something like:

1. Take the value of the pointer `x`, store it in an unseen temporary.
2. Increment the address in `x`.
3. Apply the indirection operator `*` to the  address saved to temp during (1). This is equivalent to `*x` before the increment.

Since you do nothing with the resulting valuation (3) becomes irrelavent and, `*x++;` is equivalent to `x++;` in final behavior: an increment of the address held in `x` equivalent to one type-width (`int`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Declaration..

```
 #define n 5 
 void sort(int, int *); 
 main() 
 { 
  int i,a[n]; 
        printf("enter the values"); 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        { 
          scanf("%d",&a[i]); 
        }
  sort(n,a);
 } 

 void sort(int m, int *x)
 { 
   int i,j,temp,k; 
         for(i=1;i<=m-1;i++) 
         {
           for(j=1;j<=m-1;j++)
           {
             if(*(x+j-1)>=*(x+j))
             {
              temp=*(x+j-1);
              *(x+j-1)=*(x+j); 
              *(x+j)=temp;
             }
           }
         } 
   for(k=0;k<m;k++)
   {
     printf("\n%d\n",*(x)); 
     x++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Only one line is changed. Instead of    void sort(int m, int *x);  use   void sort(int, int *);